# Populating a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Suppose that you have the following table:

```
LogID   UserID  Date                Action
1       Bob     2013-05-23 13:30:27 1
2       Bill    2013-05-23 13:31:36 1
3       Bob     2013-05-23 13:32:45 2
4       Bill    2013-05-23 13:35:12 2
```

You then create a `GridView` and populate it with the `Date` and `Action` columns:

```
Date                Action
2013-05-23 13:30:27 1
2013-05-23 13:31:36 1
2013-05-23 13:32:45 2
2013-05-23 13:35:12 2
```

What can you do so that (in the `GridView`) instead of displaying either `1` or `2` under `Action`, it displays `Clock-In` or `Clock-Out`, respectively?

Thanks in advance!

---

This is my query (the identifiers are irrelevant to the question). Where can I add a case statement here?

```
var Entries = from entries in db.EmployeeTimeClocks
              where entries.Date.Value.Day == DateTime.Now.Day &&
                    entries.UserId == AppCommon.Security.CurrentUser.UserId
              orderby entries.ID descending
              select entries;
```

Comment: Make another table with foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a case statement

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aa91e/3
```

This is the SQL

```
SELECT LogID, UserId, Date,
CASE Action
WHEN 1 THEN 'Clock-In'
ELSE 'Clock-Out'
END
FROM MyTable
```

**Edit**

With LINQ to SQL you will use your select as

```
var Entries = from entries in db.EmployeeTimeClocks
where entries.Date.Value.Day == DateTime.Now.Day &&
entries.UserId == AppCommon.Security.CurrentUser.UserId
orderby entries.ID descending
select new { 
    UserId = entries.UserId,
    //Other fields
    Clock = (entries.ClockId == 1 ? "Clock In" : "Clock Out")
};
```

Comment: I am using C# LINQ-to-SQL. See the OP for my query. Do you know what equivalent statements I would have to use?

Answer (score 1):

### First

I don't know what you want to do with this. But if you only two actions are 1 and 2 (In or Out) you should call you column "Clocked-In" and make it a `Bit` type.

### Now

You should do this on the SQL side.

You could simply create another table in relation ([ForeignKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933117%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)) with this one :

```
Actions

  | ID  |  Name     |
  ------------------
  |1    | Clock-In  |
  |2    | Clock-Out |
```

You could also change your query with a case statement that returns the right name.

I don't have your query here so this is just an example :

```
SELECT CASE Action WHEN 1 THEN 'Clock-In' ELSE 'Clock-Out' END
```

In this case make sure the only two possible options are 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the template column and then set the text like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" >
    <ItemTemplate><%# (Eval("Action")==1) ? "ClockIn" : "ClockOut" %></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use codebehind try looking at the GridView's RowDataBound Event

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDatabound(object source, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get Row Data
            //if(value == 1/2)                
            //re-assign to DataGrid's Row

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //HandleException
        }
    }
```